# Spark Dataframes AND/OR in the same cell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark DataFrame like below:

DF1

```
join_key  d1 d2 d3
 a        1   1  1
 b        0   1  0
```

DF2

```
join_key  d1 d2 d3
 a        1   0  0
 b        0   1  0
```

all values in d1,d2,d3 are 1 or 0, and both DataFrames have same columns and join_key value. I want to generate result like "AND" in each cell besides join_key, like below:

Result = DF1 & DF2  (do AND operation in each cell in d1,d2,d3)

```
join_key  d1 d2 d3
 a        1   0  0
 b        0   1  0
```

I wonder is that possible to achieve that in Spark DataFrame? How to generate that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need use `union`, not `join`, because you have exactly the same schema in both dataframes. If so you could simple use `min` aggregation function. If you have multiple columns you could iterate over it and generate the same transformation, here is an example:

```
val commonColumns = (df1.columns.toSet & df2.columns.toSet).filter(_ != "join_key").toSeq
commonColumns

df1.union(df2)
    .groupBy("join_key")
    .agg(count(lit(1)) as "cnt", 
        commonColumns.map(c => when(min(col(c)) > 0, 1).otherwise(0) as c):_*)
    .select("join_key", commonColumns:_*)
        .show
```

The output is:

```
+--------+---+---+---+
|join_key| d1| d2| d3|
+--------+---+---+---+
|       b|  0|  1|  0|
|       a|  1|  0|  0|
+--------+---+---+---+
```